# D3 force render speed

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm having trouble finding the setting for how fast a d3-force graph renders. What I am asking about is not the number of iterations or alpha parameters, but the speed of the render cycle itself. What I am trying to accomplish is a instantaneous or instantaneous rendering of nodes on the componentDidUpdate hook.

My hook code (I believe this is answerable self-contained, but will add more ctx if not):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<IProps>, prevState: Readonly<IState>, snapshot?: any): void {
    const links : Array<Link> = [];
    this.props.nodes.forEach((n : any) => {
      if (!n.dependsOn) {
        return;
      }
      n.dependsOn.forEach((index : any) => {
        links.push({ source: index, target: n.id });
      });
    })
    this.simulation = forceSimulation(this.props.nodes)
    .force(
      "link",
      forceLink()
        .id((d : any) => d.id)
        .links(links)
        .distance(100)
        .strength(0.9)
    )
    .alpha(1)
    .alphaMin(0.1)
    .force("x", forceX(150).strength(0.5))
    .force("charge", forceManyBody().strength(0.01))
    .force(
      "y",
      forceY()
        .y(node => {
          return this._calcPath(node) * 150 - 50;
        })
        .strength((node : any) => {
          let dependedOn = this._nodeDependedOn(node);

          if (!dependedOn || node.dependsOn.length < 1) {
          return 3;
          }
          return 0;
        })
    )
    .force("collide", forceCollide(this.props.radius));

        this.simulation.on("tick", () =>
          this.setState({
            links: links,
            nodes: this.state.nodes
          })
        );
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any pause between applications of `tick` while the simulation is running so I don't think you can speed it up in the way that you suggest. What you *can* control is the number of steps per render using `simulation.tick`. If you take 300 steps right away, you should effectively generate the final layout right away.

The implementation in [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/ebe85db08d365106) yields the following result:

```html
<div id="observablehq-viewof-steps_per_tick-39ec7ec3"></div>
<div id="observablehq-animation-39ec7ec3"></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/inspector@5/dist/inspector.css">
<script type="module">
import {Runtime, Inspector} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/runtime@5/dist/runtime.js";
import define from "https://api.observablehq.com/d/ebe85db08d365106@55.js?v=3";
new Runtime().module(define, name => {
  if (name === "viewof steps_per_tick") return new Inspector(document.querySelector("#observablehq-viewof-steps_per_tick-39ec7ec3"));
  if (name === "animation") return new Inspector(document.querySelector("#observablehq-animation-39ec7ec3"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Comprehensive and thorough answer - thank you!